# graph theory DFS get the path from start to end node

Tags: python, recursion, graph-theory

i need only a one path from source to destination node,to return from this function, but this function doesn't stop after the path is discovered.
i only used return when the end node is found.
how can i end this when the path is found.
my situation only have one path , and no loops
one node have maximum 4 child nodes

```
def  dfs(gpdic,start,end,visited,path):
   visited[start] = 1
   path.append(start)
   print(f"start node {start}")

   if start == end:
       print(f"this is the path {path}")
       return path
   else:
       print(f"stack {path}")
       for node in gpdic[start]:
           print(f" in node - {node}")
           if visited[node]== -1 and node != -1 and node != 0 :
               print(f" calling for next recursive funtion {node} ")
               dfs(gpdic,node,end,visited,path)
               #return path
    po =  path.pop()
    print(f" poped last {po}")
    visited[start] = -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gp = {1: [2, -1, -1, -1], 2: [3, 4, 1, 5], 3: [6, -1, 2, 7],
    4:[-1, -1, -1, 2], 5: [-1, 2, -1, -1], 6: [-1, -1, 3, -1],
    7[-1, 3, -1, -1]}


    visited = [-1] * 12
    path = []
    pathret = dfs(gp,7,4,visited,path)
    print(f"finale path - > {pathret}")
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved just need to get the return variable from function and compare it

```
def dfs(gpdic,start,end,visited,path):
   visited[start] = 1
   path.append(start)
   print(f"start node {start}")

   if start == end:
       print(f"this is the path {path}")
       return path
   else:
       print(f"stack {path}")
       for node in gpdic[start]:
           print(f" in node - {node}")
           if visited[node]== -1 and node != -1 and node != 0 :
               print(f" calling for next recursive funtion {node} ")
               l = dfs(gpdic,node,end,visited,path)
               if l is not None:
                   return path
    po =  path.pop()
    print(f" poped last {po}")
    visited[start] = -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gp = {1: [2, -1, -1, -1], 2: [3, 4, 1, 5], 3: [6, -1, 2, 7],
    4:[-1, -1, -1, 2], 5: [-1, 2, -1, -1], 6: [-1, -1, 3, -1],
    7[-1, 3, -1, -1]}


visited = [-1] * 12
path = []
pathret = dfs(gp,7,4,visited,path)
print(f"finale path - > {pathret}")
```